# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
        skinsPath : 'images/layer-skins/',
        skin : 'fullwidth',
        thumbnailNavigation : 'hover',
        hoverPrevNext : false,
        responsive : false,
        responsiveUnder : 940,
        sublayerContainer : 900
    });
});     
</script>
```

i have upload a slider but it is giving this error in console,,i have tried every thing but cant find the solution it only show one image..please help me out...

URL:-http://uzodocs.com/PROJECTS/wiki/wikicapitel.php

Answer (score 0):

According to the plugin [documentation](http://www.docs.purethemes.net/sukces/layerslider/documentation/documentation.html#setup) you should place the `<script>` tags in the `<head>` section of your document. It seems that you are including them in the `<body>` tag.